# Rails/net-ssh - ssh to remote server with private key in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to ssh to a remote server using a private key through Heroku.

I'm using this gem https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh to complete the request and have everything working fine locally.

The reason why everything works fine locally is because I have the private key saved with the passphrase entered. When I deploy to Heroku, I'm unable to use the agent like I have it on my PC and so the connection fails.

I have changed the settings on the connection using `net-ssh` to not use the agent but still can't get it functioning.

Worst case I will have to create a separate API call in php hosted elsewhere to complete this connection but I'm hoping I can make it work through my rails app in Heroku.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
options = {}    
options[:key_data] = ENV['LANDING_PAGE_SSH_KEY']
options[:keys_only] = true
options[:use_agent] = false
options[:verbose] = :debug
options[:port] = '18765'
options[:passphrase] = ENV['SSH_KEY_PASSPHRASE']

Net::SSH.start(ENV['SERVER_HOSTNAME'], ENV['SERVER_USERNAME'], options) do |ssh|

end
```

I've entered the private key in a global variable and everything else that I would need. This also works locally without using the agent but fails on Heroku with this message:

```
[2017-07-21T19:20:35.506794 #4] DEBUG -- socket[383b2bc]: read 52 bytes
2017-07-21T19:20:35.507070+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.507016 #4] DEBUG -- socket[383b2bc]: received packet nr 3 type 6 len 28
2017-07-21T19:20:35.507262+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.507210 #4] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fd3f610f914]: trying none
2017-07-21T19:20:35.507477+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.507412 #4] DEBUG -- socket[383b2bc]: queueing packet nr 4 type 50 len 44
2017-07-21T19:20:35.507603+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.507553 #4] DEBUG -- socket[383b2bc]: sent 68 bytes
2017-07-21T19:20:35.536336+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.536194 #4] DEBUG -- socket[383b2bc]: read 52 bytes
2017-07-21T19:20:35.536472+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.536422 #4] DEBUG -- socket[383b2bc]: received packet nr 4 type 51 len 28
2017-07-21T19:20:35.536573+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.536526 #4] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fd3f610f914]: allowed methods: publickey
2017-07-21T19:20:35.536657+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.536612 #4] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[3fd3f6103e84]: none failed
2017-07-21T19:20:35.536749+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-07-21T19:20:35.536703 #4] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fd3f610f914]: trying publickey
2017-07-21T19:20:35.537566+00:00 app[web.1]: Enter passphrase for <key in memory>:Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 337ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2017-07-21T19:20:35.538404+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-21T19:20:35.538406+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device):
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to add the private key to the server's ssh setup

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/path-to-private-key
```

and it started working.

Comment: What does it mean, how did you do that?

Comment: @Sebastien you need to run this command on a server that's running your code. net-ssh just uses an ssh client on the underlying host machine, so you need to tell your client about the private key that you want to use for ssh authentication by adding it. https://www.ssh.com/ssh/add